# Tomcat compatible with springboot 3.1.0

Tags: spring-boot, apache, tomcat

We are upgrading our springboot project from 2.6.6 to 3.1.0 so for that I am doing an analysis to find out which Tomcat version should we use 10.1.8 or 10.1.10, but couldn't find anything for that.
PS JDK 17 and maven 3.8.8

I tried going through both versions release notes but couldn't find anything there.

Comment: 10.1.x which whatever you like, but why not use the Spring Boot managed version? Do you manually deploy or use an embedded container? If the latter why bother with the version?